# Load Silverlight Class Library on demand (MEF?)

Tags: silverlight, .net-4.5, mef, silverlight-5.0

I need to separate bunch of user controls into a Class Library and then load it on demand.
These are rarely used so I dont want them loaded with the application start.

I have rather large enterprise app and there is a set of functionality to configure things which use by a the app administrator.

Say the administrator wants to open page where is a menu with number of user controls to display. The menu is part of the main application and once he/she clicks on a menu item a certain user control needs to be loaded from the Class Library.

I understand MEF can do that easily. Could someone please describe how this needs to be implemented from the high point of view.

Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to understand MEF is this:
http://ajay555.wordpress.com/2009/11/30/managed-extensibility-framework-mef-example/

In a gross mode:

-You need to indicate which elements you want to export with the [export] tag

-You need the [import] tag to indicate where you wanna load these elements.

-You need a Lazy<> variable to keep your "inactive" elements while you don't use them

-You need to manipulate everything using interfaces.

Regarding specifically your question title, when you compile a class library it generates a .xap file, which you can access using MEF and then get all elements with the [export] tag you have created.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah i think that what i was looking for - a road map.. cheers

Comment: Nice! They have part 2 as well -> http://ajay555.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/managed-extensibility-framework-mef-example-%E2%80%93-part-ii/